# MS Access date format changed after replacing the native DB to SQLServer

Tags: date, ms-access-2010

I have replaced the native DB of a MS Access application to SQL Server. The date format in the forms of the application got changed after the replacement and started creating conflicts. Is there a way in Access to revert the data format of the forms globally?

Original date format -> mm/dd/yyyy

Changed date format -> yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

Formats are for display only and cannot cause "conflicts".

So, most likely, you have converted your *DateTime* fields to the *DateTime2* data type in SQL Server. This Access can't read, thus the values are converted to text, and this will cause all sorts of problems.